# In Remix unable to switch from Javascript VM to Injected Web3

Tags: solidity, walletconnect, remix-tests

I'm looking to learn the high-level basics of code so I am watching and following along to freeCodeCamp.org and their [16-hour-long video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=6906s). I am 2 hours and 5 minutes into the video and it's time to deploy it to a testnet. I need to switch my environment from Javascript VM (london) to Injected web3 but for some reason I can't do it, it won't even let me click in Injected web3, the screen reads "cant detect network"  ... anyone know how I can fix this?

Appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: Do you have metamask plugin installed in your browser?

Comment: you need MetaMask installed; logged in and an account created just for testing; connect it to the Remix website; connect it the target testnet. You'll need some testnet Eth so get that from a faucet for that testnet

Answer (score 0):

After a month break I've hit the same problem, it was working fine before.

From googling this seems to be an intermittent bug in Remix based on the versions of Metamask, Chrome and Remix being used.

Switched to Firefox and worked Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ya it's a common glitch in RemixIDE, i have get this error many times. And correct it by this method:-

Step 1. Make sure Metamask is unlocked

Step 2. ReFresh (ctrl+shift+r) Remix

Now try to connect. It will work (most probably).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found this on the documentation, if you can't see JavaScript VM, just use Remix VM (London)

Answer (score 0):

1. **First** of all make sure you are using the correct Remix IDE (There is
   a random forked version out there). The real version is on
   Remix.ethereum.org
2. **Secondly**, use Chrome browser as that's the one I found to work most
   constantly. It is also currently broken on Brave browser. IDK if you
   are using that.
3. And **lastly**, first unlock your metamask browser add-on so you can
   access your wallet and try again :)